# MYSQL For/While Loop

Tags: mysql, loops

Is it possible to do a For or While loop in MYSQL?

I've got the following code extract, but the full code goes up to home_id_15, home_score_15, away_id_15 and away_score_15:

```
$query3 = '
SELECT match_date, fixture_id, COUNT(a.home) AS home, SUM(a.points) AS points FROM
    (  
      SELECT match_date, fixture_id, home_id_1 AS home, home_score_1 AS points FROM scores
      WHERE home_id_1 =' .intval($_REQUEST['ID']).'  
      UNION ALL  
      SELECT match_date, fixture_id, away_id_1 AS home, away_score_1 AS points 
      FROM scores
      WHERE away_id_1 =' .intval($_REQUEST['ID']).'  
      UNION ALL  
      SELECT match_date, fixture_id, home_id_2 AS home, home_score_2 AS points 
      FROM scores
      WHERE home_id_2 =' .intval($_REQUEST['ID']).'  
      UNION ALL  
      SELECT match_date, fixture_id, away_id_2 AS home, away_score_2 AS points 
      FROM scores
      WHERE away_id_2 =' .intval($_REQUEST['ID']).'  
      UNION ALL) a  
     GROUP BY match_date'
```

The first and second sub-SELECTS are basically being repeated until they reach 15.

This seems a bit long-winded and I was wondering if it's possible to use a loop in MYSQL to output

```
home_id_1, home_score_1, away_id_1, away_score_1 [up to] home_id_15, home_score_15, away_id_15, away_score_15
```

, respectively?

Thanks,
Dan.

Comment: you can do a while loop in stored procs. If you can *not* use an sp then don't

Comment: It would be best to normalize your schema, so you don't have 15 different sets of columns to process. They should be in 15 different rows of a table.

Comment: I totally wouldn't use this schema. No offense intended. You can't join nuttin' and the indexes, well, no strategy.

Comment: In the last 2 or 3 months there have been a few questions on a `homeId` and `awayId` for matches on the stack. I recollect a decent join strategy with those questions. A search is [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5bmysql%5d%20home%20away%20team)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you might need to normalize your database a little bit more.  Let's say you had 6 scores for each row.  Instead of making each score a column, make a separate table called "scores" or something like that with a foreign key column and a score column.  Then join the table with this scores table.

Example:

- TABLE: team

  - team_id
  - name
- TABLE: scores

  - team_id
  - score

```
SELECT t.*, s.score 
FROM team t
join scores s 
on t.team_id=s.team_id;
```

Todo: Add the concept of `matches` into your schema and the `Join`

Comment: Thanks very much.  Looks like I need to re-evaluate that side of the database.  I have a teams, players and scores and venues table.  The home_id, away_id, etc all point towards the players.id foreign key, but there's a lot of players, and a lot of scores, hence this getting a bit unwieldly.